# debugging issue with genymotion in android

Tags: android, android-studio, genymotion

I have installed genymotion and installed plugin for that also in android studio and also given genymotion path in there.. Genymotion emulator device also getting opened but the issue is I am not able to run the app as this error keeps coming while running it. App runs fine on android provided emulator but it takes ample time to build and run. Suggest me something please,,, thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: And what is the error message?

Comment: Error installing apk file

Comment: What do you think about using other debugs tool? Have you heard about GapDebug?

Comment: Did you uninstall the app first?  Also check that you are using the right Build Variant

Comment: App is not there in genymotion emulator device..

Comment: Yes still I can check build variant..